# How to link the externally generated objects in waf?

Tags: makefile, waf

I have a requirement where in I want to build the object files separately and link them together. Specifically I have a `Makefile` to build some objects which I want to call from the `wscript` file. I am able to call `make` command from the `wscript` file. But I am not able to figure out how to link these objects.

All the file contents are given below.

file1.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

 extern void hello () ;

 int main ()
 {
    printf ("Hello file1\n") ;
    hello () ;
    return 0 ;  
 }
```

file2.c :

```
 #include <stdio.h> 

 void hello ()
 {
printf ("Hello file2\n") ;  
 }
```

Following are the contents of `wscript` file.

```
def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):
    bld(rule='cp ./../Makefile .')
    bld(rule='make', always='True')
    bld.program(features='c', 
    source=['file1.c'],
        includes=['build'],
    target='prog')
```

Makefile:

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc

file2.o:
$(CC) -c ./../file2.c -o ./file2.o
```

Note : Beware of copying Makefile from here directly because of tabs.

Comment: Why not replace the Makefile by entries in waf files?